# Можно ли поменять фон MDI окна?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vb.net

Можно ли поменять фон MDI окна, и если да то как это сделать встроенными средствами .NET?

Comment: Дочерней формы, или родительской всё же?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control is MdiClient)
    {
        control.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft [советует](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/319465) делать так (код на С#):
В обработчике `OnLoad` главной формы пропишите:

```
MdiClient ctlMDI;

foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
{
   try
   {
      ctlMDI = (MdiClient) ctl;
      //Устанавливаем цвет дочерней формы таким же, как и у главной:
      ctlMDI.BackColor = this.BackColor;
   }
   catch (InvalidCastException exc)
   {
      //Обработка ошибок.
   }                 
}
// Создаем и Показываем дочернюю форму:п
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.MdiParent = this;
frm.Show();
```

Comment: try-catch вместо if-as :(